# Flexbox in React Native

Tags: css, react-native, sass, flexbox

I have a `SafeAreaView` and I am trying to apply some styles to it.

If I use inline styles, my text is centered on the screen.

```
const thisStyle = {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
}

    <SafeAreaView  style={thisStyle}>
      ...
    </SafeAreaView>
```

However, if I define the styles in a *scss* file and import it in my component, the flexbox is not applied.

```
import styles from './login.scss';

...


<SafeAreaView  style={styles.container}>
  ...
</SafeAreaView>
```

scss:

```
@import './src/base.scss';

    .container {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: $plump-purple;
        align-items: 'center';
        justify-content: 'center'
    }
```

Note that the other properties work (the background changes color) the only thing that appears not working is the flexbox. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it this way.

**Main Class**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

export default class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>...</SafeAreaView>;
  }
}
```

**Style Class**

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'plump-purple',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: I updated the answer please check you are using scss which is not recommended. the update have the right way to implement styling. Use it like this.

Comment: Should the Style Class be on the same file as the Main Class? Or can I create a Style.js file for each component? What is the common standard?

Comment: You can do both way. If you have large style file then you can use each style for one component.